# Is there any difference between these two?

Tags: c, multiplication, associativity

I donno if this is possible or not but am confused.
Are they both same?
I know that in the first case we are allocating memory dynamically for 20 elements of type int.

```
int *p;
p=(int *) malloc(20*sizeof(int));
```

and

```
p=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*20);
```

Comment: They are both the same. Multiplication is commutative, therefore `20*sizeof(int)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)*20`. malloc just takes the _number of bytes_ to allocate, so either way around will give you the correct result - e.g. `amount_of_space_for_int * 20` v.s. `20 * amount_of_space_for_int`

Comment: ok thanks ,it cleared my doubt.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:pointer] or [tag:malloc]. The same is true of any multiplication operator in C, and of others such as addition as well.

Comment: OT #1: In C it is not necessary and therefore frowned upon to cast the `void*` returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: OT #2: Instead of a `sizeof` operation with a type, better use it with the dereferenced target: `p = malloc(20 * sizeof *p);` (please note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function).

Comment: When you multiply by any *factor*, the order of in which you multiply the factors does not change the *product*. That is the *associative property of multiplication*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "the order of in which you multiply the factors" is _communitive_, not _associative_.  Associative is a problem as `int * int * size_t` can overflow where `size_t * int * int` does not.

Comment: @chux -- yes, thank you for the catch! Associative is *grouping*... That's what happens when it's been over 45 years since you had basic math `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin For me, **co**mmunative is 2, **ass**ociative is 3.  And we should not [assume](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1339:_When_You_Assume).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The word is *commutative*, not "communitive" or "communative".

Comment: @nielsen Yes _commutative_,  The spell checker did not help with the in-word bolding and spelling is my Achilles heel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that `sizeof` operator returns type: `size_t`.

In the case of `int * size_t` (`20*sizeof(int)`) versus `size_t * int` (`sizeof(int) * 20`): the product is the same as the narrower type is widened to the other first and multiplication in C is *commutative*: `a*b` equals `b*a`.

The situation changes with `int * int * size_t` versus `size_t * int * int` as in C, multiplication is not *associative*.  The first multiples `int * int` (with an `int` product), then does `int * size_t`.  With select values, the first multiplication may overflow whereas `size_t * int * int` does not.

When more than 2 objects may be multiplied, best to make certain the widest multiplication happens first and subsequently: example `size_t * int * int`.

---

> Is there any difference between these two?

With only 2 objects to multiply, code in whatever way you like.
I like to lead with the likely wider type.

---

Since the cast is not needed and sizing to the object is easier to code right, review and maintain, consider:

```
p = malloc(sizeof p[0] * 20);
if (p == NULL) {
  TBD(); // Handle out-of-memory
}
```

Comment: Regarding the rather subjective arguments of coding style, check out [How to properly use malloc?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285898/285910#answer-285910)

Comment: `size_t * int * int` can also overflow.

Comment: @Lundin In reviewing compliable code `p.member = malloc(sizeof p.member[0])` vs. `p.member = malloc(sizeof(int))`, the first is  correct on its face.  The 2nd obliges a hunt for the definition of `p` and then its type.  The type definition may well lie in another file.  Concerning "easier to code right, review and maintain", it is the _review_ part that is strongest of using size of the object over using the size of the type.  As with such _style_ issues, best to code to the group's coding standard as there is much entrenchment on this issue .

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 True that `size_t * int * int` _can_ overflow, yet `size_t * int * int` will not overflow for many combinations that `int * int *size_t` does.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica A seasoned programmer does not write coding using _any_ variable without looking up its type first. Luckily, "modern" (as in made this millennium) IDEs make it easy to track down identifiers with a single key press or at worst some right-click menu. So it's a poor rationale - we shouldn't use _any_ variable in any context without knowing its type first.

Comment: @Lundin As mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76601840/is-there-any-difference-between-these-two/76602546?noredirect=1#comment135065707_76602546), an advantage to `p = malloc(sizeof p[0])` is in review. That is not about writing code, but others (not the original maybe junior author) reviewing. IDEs may help when available, yet not apply as in reviewing code here or in [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for example.  The 1 click look-up is still more than 0 afforded with `sizeof p[0]`.  It is a good rational to not even need the context when its irrelevant.